# The application couldn't find "libnexgo_sdkemvjni.so"

Tags: java, android, sdk, pos

I'm trying To use NexGo SDK to print the receipt Using NexGo p200
but when I run the application I got the error that shown in the image below.

[image]

The Code is :

```
public void print() {
    try {
        deviceEngine =APIProxy.getDeviceEngine(MainActivity.this);
        Log.e("device",deviceEngine.toString());
    }catch (RuntimeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printer = deviceEngine.getPrinter();
    printer.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    printer.initPrinter();
    printer.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    printer.setLetterSpacing(5);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_merchantname), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_merchantno), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_terminalno), getString(R.string.print_operator), 24, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_issurebank), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_shoudan), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_expiredate), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.cardnum), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_cardinfo), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_tradetype), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_batchno), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_voucher), getString(R.string.print_authorcode), 24, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_refrenceno), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_tradedate), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_amount), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.money), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_beizhu), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_originalvoucher), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_addinfo), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendBarcode(getString(R.string.print_barcode), 50, 0, 2, BarcodeFormatEnum.CODE_128, AlignEnum.CENTER);
    printer.appendQRcode(getString(R.string.print_qrcode), 200, AlignEnum.CENTER);
    printer.appendPrnStr("---------------------------", 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_cardhold), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr("\n", 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr("\n", 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr("\n", 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr("---------------------------", 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_cardhold_ensure), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_cardhold_ensure), 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr("---------------------------", 24, AlignEnum.LEFT, false);
    printer.appendPrnStr(getString(R.string.print_merchant_dan), 24, AlignEnum.RIGHT, false);
    printer.startPrint(false, new OnPrintListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrintResult(final int retCode) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, retCode + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question. The images are missing.

Comment: sorry the image link

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtb2H.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the `java.library.path` system property not being correct. You can try fixing it by passing the `-Djava.library.path=<your-directory-containing-the-so-file>` parameter.

Comment: I added all *.so files to the jniLibs folder but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

[inside app >> build.gradle >> defaultConfig >> please paste this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoASd.png)

ndk {
moduleName "app"
abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
}